# How to make NSTableView not reuse TableCellViews

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I would like my view-based-NSTableview to not reuse previously generated TableCellViews that are scrolled out of scope. I figure that this would be possible with UITableView by overwriting dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: to return nil. Ist there is similar solution for NSTableView?

-

My Background: I have a quite complex view-based-tableView bound to ManagedObjects in the usual way (i.e. table-content, -selection and -sortdescriptor are bound to an arraycontroller and the tableCellView-elements bind to the objectValue).

The table has about 20 columns but at most 400 rows. Scrolling is really slow, but time-profiling indicates that no single source of slowness exists (largest single method-call takes about 5% of time). After caching the derived/custom properties of my ManagedObject without much performance-boost, i'm now trying to cache the views (to avoid the frequent rebind of the tablecellViews when a view comes into scope).

What i'm trying at the moment is to not bind the table-content, but to get my views using the NSDatasource-protocol. There in

```
-(NSView*) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

i would like to return cached TableCellViews if they exist. Otherwise i create a new one via

```
[self.table makeViewWithIdentifier:... owner:self];
```

Since makeViewWithIdentifier may return views that are already cached by me, the table-content gets messed up with wrong cells.

Performance is significantly better with this approach...

-

Other ideas on making scrolling more performant are also appriciated.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if you got anywhere with this. I think I have the opposite problem in that my NSTableView is *not* re-using cells for some reason. I tried PXListView, but that had worse performance and lots of bugs, so I'd like to stick with NSTableView but work out how to make it cache views which I think it's supposed to do. As far as your problem goes, would you be able to create a unique identifier for each view or is that going to cause terrible memory usage?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your tableView:viewForTableColumn: implementation set the .identifier on the returned view to nil. That will prevent the table from caching it. You could then manage your own cache. FWIW, you don't have to even use makeViewWithIdentifier: at all; you can just manually create your views from scratch, instead of using that method (which loads the pre-setup views form the NIB).

However, if you are having performance problems, it would be better to address those by looking at what is slow and why. You didn't provide information on why it is slow, so it is hard to say what to do. 20 columns is a lot. You might get better performance by attempting to reduce your layer count by using canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer, on the NSTableCellView, or the NSTableRowView. But there are lots of caveats and things to be aware of when doing this.

corbin

Comment: Also, just like in UIKit and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:, you could override makeViewWithIdentifier and implement your own caching mechanism (or have it return nil).

Comment: Are you saying that the return from tableView:viewForTableColumn: is only used for caching the reuse pool? Is there any current info on how many views would be egregiously slow or a way to know how big the reuse pool is? Any way to know how that might tie in to the scroll view overdraw API?

Comment: No, that isn't what I said. The return from tableView:viewForTableColumn: is the very view that the table places in that given location. When the table goes to remove the view (because it is no longer needed), it is cached ONLY if the view.identifier is non-nil. Otherwise, the view is tossed out and freed.

Comment: For performance problems, you need to use Instruments and sample.