# Prevent NSOutlineView (or NSTableView) from redrawing on scroll

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

It seems that my view-based OutlineView try to re-render text every time user scrolling. I think that was because it tried to save memory by re-using rows that fall outside of visible rectangle, then re-render new data to those old views. How can I disable this? I'm willing to sacrifice memory to archive this so that I can get better scrolling performance. (I have tried with various optimize like layer or so, but no luck).

EDIT: There is another question with same purpose as mine here [How to make NSTableView not reuse TableCellViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810818/how-to-make-nstableview-not-reuse-tablecellviews), but no answer yet :(

Comment: How can disabling row reuse boost your scrolling performance?

Comment: well as said above, when the tableview is scrolled, it have to render the new text to the reused cell, and my table contain a lot of text while text rendering is a expensive process

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused -- it doesn't re-render the text. The table only shows views for the visible area (caveat below), and pulls in new views as you scroll -- potentially re-using old views.

You provide the view. Use the delegate method viewForTableColumn:row: and return your own cached view for a given row.

But that isn't going to prevent drawing; the view will likely still get marked dirty and draw.

I don't think you are asking the right question. It sounds like you have a performance problem. To help you with that, we'd have to see samples or instrument traces.

- Caveat: Responsive Scrolling will pull in views that are in the non visible area. See the AppKit release notes about this.

corbin